# CAS SSO - CASPRIVACY and TGC

Tags: cookies, spring-security, cas, jasig

I am new to CAS and I am trying to understood more on CASPRIVACY and TGC cookie parameters.

In order to invalidate a CAS SSO session, is it enough to set CASPRIVACY and TGC cookie values to empty or is there anything in addition that we need to do?

Do we have to set an default value for CASPRIVACY or is there any property file to manage this in CAS server?

Answer (score 0):

To invalidate a CAS SSO session, you need to call the /cas/logout endpoint which will remove these cookies but also remove the user identity associated with the CASTGC.
This will remove the application sessions as well if you have properly configured the application logout endpoints and the CAS services

Comment: I am calling the /cas/logout and it is invalidating the session in CAS. I am also seeing that it is also removing the TGC cookie from browser. But it is only logging the application from where I called the /cas/logout. But the other cas client application is not logged out at all. Hence I was doubtful if CAS needs to clear anything else from cookie. Any pointers?

Comment: Is the other application CAS service configured with BACK CHANNEL on CAS server side? Is the other CAS client application able to handle CAS logout requests?

Comment: Yes, the CAS service is configured as BACK_CHANNEL on CAS server side. But only the CAS service from which the CAS logout was requested is logged out. The other CAS client application are not able to handle CAS logout requests. All the CAS client applications have been configured with SingleSignOutFilter and the SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener.

Comment: Better ask the question on CAS mailing list with your logs

Comment: Appreciate your responses so far. I have already asked this question in the CAS mailing list, [Click here to go to question in CAS Developer group](https://groups.google.com/a/apereo.org/forum/#!topic/cas-dev/LUtaFxzef78)

Comment: I believe there we couple of mailing list for CAS. I posted in jasig-cas-user group also, [click here to access the question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jasig-cas-user/Fk2ipKErgmk)